# Spark incremental loading overwrite old record

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, etl, presto

I have a requirement to do the incremental loading to a table by using Spark (PySpark)

Here's the example:

Day 1

```
id | value
-----------
1  | abc
2  | def
```

Day 2

```
id | value
-----------
2  | cde
3  | xyz
```

Expected result

```
id | value
-----------
1  | abc
2  | cde
3  | xyz
```

This can be done easily in relational database, 
Wondering whether this can be done in Spark or other transformational tool, e.g. Presto?

Comment: just `union` two dataframes and remove duplicates + sort, you will get desired output.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Here you go!
First Dataframe:

```
 >>> list1 = [(1, 'abc'),(2,'def')]
 >>> olddf = spark.createDataFrame(list1, ['id', 'value'])
 >>> olddf.show();
 +---+-----+
 | id|value|
 +---+-----+
 |  1|  abc|
 |  2|  def|
 +---+-----+
```

Second Dataframe:

```
>>> list2 = [(2, 'cde'),(3,'xyz')]
>>> newdf = spark.createDataFrame(list2, ['id', 'value'])
>>> newdf.show();
+---+-----+
| id|value|
+---+-----+
|  2|  cde|
|  3|  xyz|
+---+-----+
```

Now join and merge these two datafame using full outer join and use coalesce function while select and can replace the null values wih user defined values.

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import *

>>> df = olddf.join(newdf, olddf.id == newdf.id,'full_outer').select(coalesce(olddf.id,newdf.id).alias("id"),coalesce(newdf.value,olddf.value).alias("value"))
>>> df.show();
+---+-----+
| id|value|
+---+-----+
|  1|  abc|
|  3|  xyz|
|  2|  cde|
+---+-----+
```

I hope this should solve your problem. :-)

Comment: Thanks for your step by step instruction, wondering if this can be done easier by dropDuplicates(["id"]) ?

Answer (score 2):

dataframe appending is done by `union` function in pyspark. I'll demo with an example and create 2 dataframes as you mentioned in the question.

```
from pyspark.sql.types import Row
df1 = sqlContext.createDataFrame([Row(id=1,value="abc"),Row(id=2,value="def")])

df1.show()
+---+-----+
| id|value|
+---+-----+
|  1|  abc|
|  2|  def|
+---+-----+

df2 = sqlContext.createDataFrame([Row(id=2,value="cde"),Row(id=3,value="xyz")])
df2.show()
+---+-----+
| id|value|
+---+-----+
|  2|  cde|
|  3|  xyz|
+---+-----+
```

Lets do a `union` between the two dataframes and you will get the desired result.

```
df2.union(df1).dropDuplicates(["id"]).show()
+---+-----+
| id|value|
+---+-----+
|  1|  abc|
|  3|  xyz|
|  2|  cde|
+---+-----+
```

You can sort the output using `asc` from `pyspark.sql.functions`

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import asc


df2.union(df1).dropDuplicates(["id"]).sort(asc("id")).show()
+---+-----+
| id|value|
+---+-----+
|  1|  abc|
|  2|  cde|
|  3|  xyz|
+---+-----+
```

Comment: I think you need the sort(asc("id")) before the dropDuplicates call. Also, the dropDuplicates call you now need to pass the named optional array parameter `subset` as opposed to a string.

Answer (score 2):

Workaround, add a date column in dataframe, then rank based on id and order by date in descending and take the rank == 1. It will always give you the latest record based on id.

```
df.("rank", rank().over(Window.partitionBy($"id").orderBy($"date".desc)))
  .filter($"rank" === 1)
  .drop($"rank")
  .orderBy($"id")
  .show
```